# Is my claim true about the sign of the function?

Tags: functions, monotone-functions

I have a continuous function $f(x)$ for $0<x<a$ where $f(0)=0$. I want to know whether this function is positive or negative. From numerical data, I know that $f'(x)$ is negative, but it is not easy to prove it, but I can prove that $f'(x)$ can not be zero (this gives a contradiction). Then, does this means that the function is monotonic (either increasing or decreasing)? If so, computing $f(a)$ will clear if the function is positive or negative. Is this claim true?

Comment: Why monotonic?${}$

Comment: But it might change sign. How do you prove it doesn't?

Comment: And if $f'$ is not continuous?

Comment: You didn't mention it. Anyway, it would work, as derivatives, even non-continuous, satisfy the *intermediate value theorem*, but it is a more sophisticated theorem.

Comment: If $f$ is differentiable, it is continuous, but $f'$ is not necessarily continuous.

Comment: A small style pointer is that it would be good to say "$f$ is a differentiable function". Your argument can certainly be made very rigorous! While it's not true that derivatives have to be continuous, derivatives do have to have the intermediate value property, so indeed your derivative must be wholly positive or negative. This is sometimes called [Darboux's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darboux%27s_theorem_(analysis)). However it's not entirely clear to me from your question if what you want is a real analysis proof.

Comment: If you know $f’(x)$ is continuous, then you know that $f’$ is never positive, so the function is monotonic decreasing, by the mean value theorem.

Comment: If you're happy to quote Darboux's Theorem, then you're pretty much good (if you're also willing to quote that a function with negative or positive derivative is monotonic). However Darboux's Theorem is not entirely trivial to prove. Perhaps you could add some more context about what function you're working with and why you want to prove it's monotonic. If you're doing a real analysis course, the answer will be different to if you're just doing an introductory calculus course.

Comment: @charmin I’ve assume you have show at least one value where $f’<0$ and that $f’$ is never zero. Then if $f’$ is continuous, it can never be positive, or else somewhere it is zero by the intermediate value theorem.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews But as others mentioned it is not needed to do it. Since according to IVT, if $f'$ can not be zero, then it must be wholly positive or negative. Then by calculating $f(a)$ which is negative, I can claim that $f$ is a negative function.

Comment: @charmin that’s only true if $f’$ is continuous.